# NestJs - Fallback at configuration file for ConfigService doesn't work

Tags: nestjs

I'm using node18 and nestjs 9.3.12.

I have such configuration file:

```
export default () => ({
  AUTH_HOST: process.env.AUTH_HOST || "www.myhost.com"
});
```

at app.module I have this:

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  isGlobal: true,
  load: [configuration],
});
```

in my environment `AUTH_HOST` such record exists, it is empty:

```
AUTH_HOST=
```

I have a service that uses the ConfigService

```
class RootService {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    const authHost = this.configService.get<string>('AUTH_HOST');
  }
  // ...
}
```

so I'm expecting code  `process.env.AUTH_HOST || "www.myhost.com"` will return `"www.myhost.com"` but it returns empty string.
Changing flags of ConfigModule to `ignoreEnvFile: true` and `ignoreEnvVars: true` has no effect.

What is correct nestjs way to make a fallback to what I provide at configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these one

```
const authHost = this.configService.get<string>('AUTH_HOST','www.myhost.com')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).